# CSS media screen not working?

Tags: css

I'm new at CSS. I'm coding a very simple website, and I have some CSS code for a footer.

```
.footer {
    background: #968065;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10vw;
    color: #EEE8C6;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .footer {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
}
```

I want the media screen to hide the footer on phone, however this doesn't work. I tested the code without all the other stuff, and it works. What do you think is the problem? Thanks.

Comment: @somethinghere pay attention while editing, you made his question irrelevant by introducing the footer tag, we think it's typo issue

Comment: share your full code including HTML and other CSS

Comment: @somethinghere why insisting on editing his question? let him share his code. How you know it's his code?

Comment: Firstly check the styles since they could be overridden by other styles.

Comment: @TemaniAlif I am not _editing_ his code, I am making it possible to _test_ his code. I have not made any edits to his code except inserting a testing element.

Comment: `so I dont see anything wrong with this` --> so don't edit and let him add his relevant code

Comment: @somethinghere by creating a snippet it's like you confirm that this is his final code, you also added a HTML portion and you have no idea if it's like this or not

Comment: @somethinghere am not distracting .. who told you he's correctly using the footer class? how told you there isn't another class or ID on the footer? you don't have this information

Comment: @somethinghere actually in my opinion you are misleading potential helpers by providing an HTML code which could be different from user's. Since, HTML code is not provided it should be asked to user, but not added yourself since his code may be different what actually causes the problem. Just ask for a code, not add it yourself.

Comment: @advayratan please share your HTML code with us so we could help you by observing the whole problem but not a part of it. While working with CSS it is vital to know an HTML part also since they are working side by side.

Comment: This `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` is needed to tell the browser to use the phone's screen width, and it's better to use `display:none` so the div doesn't mess with the other element's, unless that's the intended way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First add the following meta tag to your HTML file.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Using `display: none` is a better practice than `visibility: hidden`. The former will not allocate any space in the dome, but the latter will do but be only invisible.

```
@media all and (max-width: 600px){
  .footer{
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: But this isn't the problem the OP is describing. The problem seems to be that his _media query_ doesn't work, not that his element keeps taking up space.

Comment: @somethinghere you are right, I've missed the point. Edited the post accordingly. However, I also wanted to indicate the better practice in the first place.

Comment: I actually want the visibility:hidden; but adding the meta tag helped. Thanks!